# Execute Codeigniter PHP from TCL script

Tags: php, tcl

I need to call php page inside tcl scripting page.

How to embed codeigniter php inside TCL script page ? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try use this:

```
eval "exec php -q /path/to/your/codeigniter/index.php yourController yourMethod"
```

Maybe you have to make some changes in your index.php to execute it...
I suggest you create a specific file for the cls... Make a copy of your index.php and put this at the begging of the file:

```
/* we don't need to be limited by...normal limitations */
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');

/* make sure this isn't being called by a web browser */
if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) die('Permission denied.');

/* set some constants */
define('CMD', 1);

/* manually set the URI path based on command line arguments... */
unset($argv[0]); /* ...but not the first one */
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] =  $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/' . implode('/', $argv) . '/';
```

And call this file instead of index.php...

And dont know if this will work... But this could be your start point....

Comment: I am getting this error..... Could not open input file: /var/www/html/sampleapp/auth
    while executing
"exec php -q /var/www/html/sampleapp/auth"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval "exec php -q /var/www/html/sampleapp/auth""
    ("uplevel" body line 166

Comment: when I use this eval "exec php -q /var/www/html/sampleapp/" it doesn't throw any error... but it does not display anything from php

Comment: Where is your index.php? at sampleapp or at auth directory?

Comment: its a codeigniter framework. so folder name is sampleapp and inside default controller name auth. In the controller auth i have defined index method and wrote functionalities witin it. Whenever I call http://localhost/sampleapp automatically auth controller will be executed.